# Calc formulas show up in English, how can I use them in my native language?

Tags: libreoffice, translation

I'm a brazilian user and after update to ubuntu 11.10, my LibreOffice (that here is called Broffice) is having some formulas in english and it has always being in portuguese.
Like Sum always was Soma, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If the option to use formulas in English is disabled and you're still not seeing formulas in your language, [it might be due to this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/873702).

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Calc to use the English formulas (it's really handy as most documentation is in English). Please check that it is disabled:

[image]